# Target a specific category from a custom taxonomy?

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, plugins

I am trying to target a specific category from a custom taxonomy. This is for WooCommerce.

So, the custom taxonomy is called "product_cat" and the category itself is called "adult-dvds".

This is what I tried; however, it didn't work (nothing shows up between the comment tags):

```
    <!-- Custom Fields -->
    <?php if (is_tax('product_cat','adult-dvds')) { ?> 
        <p>blah blah blah</p>
    <?php } ?>
    <!-- End Custom Fields -->
```

Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using this bit of code and it worked:

```
<?php if (has_term('adult-dvds','product_cat')) { ?> 
    <p>blah blah blah</p>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: as of 2015. This worked for me! @desi

Answer (score 0):

Are your custom taxonomy's slug is `product-cat`? The [`is_tax()` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax) need parameter of the taxonomy slug, not the id. So this should work:

```
if (is_tax('product-cat','adult-dvds')) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work.

Comment: What I mean by that is that, still, nothing is showing up between the comment tags.

Comment: are you opening with kind like /product-cat/adult-dvds?
if yes, this conditional sholud work.

Comment: Hm, it's still not working. Do you think I should be using something other than `is_tax`?